# trigger on Opportuntiy partner account

Tags: apex, trigger, community

In which release we can expect to write a trigger Opportuntiy partner account ? Does anyone have an idea on this?

Comment: Could you please **[edit]** your post to have a bit more context?

Answer (score 1):

Nobody who would be in a position to know would be able to tell you anything concrete (because of signed NDA agreements and/or Safe Harbor policy). I think you might be referring to [this Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqP8). You should vote for the Idea to make sure you get notified when, or if, this feature is implemented.